# Showing that any sequence in $[0,1]$ has a convergent subsequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

One should show that any sequence in $[0,1]$ has a convergent subsequence.

Now before even trying to prove it in general, I take one sample sequence, $x_n = |\sin(n)|$.

I think that for this sequence, the only convergent subsequence could be a constant. So $x_{nk} = x_{nk+1}$, i.e., $|\sin(m(k))| = |\sin(m(k+1))|$.

As $\sin$ is $2 \pi$ periodic, I would need some strictly increasing function $m(k)$ s.t. $m(k)  2 \pi = m(k+1)$. However, as $m : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $, I find myself unable to find such a function.

Which of my assumptions here is wrong? Could there be some convergent subsequence without the subsequence being constant? Or does an appropriate $m(k)$ exist?

Thanks for all hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a non-constant convergent subsequence. There is a sequence $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of positive integers such that

$$\langle n_k\pi-\lfloor n_k\pi\rfloor:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\to 0\;.$$

For $k\in\Bbb N$ let $m_k=\lfloor n_k\pi\rfloor$; then $\langle m_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a subsequence of the positive integers such that

$$\langle\sin m_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\to 0\;.$$

However, I really think that it’s easier simply to prove the general theorem than to find a convergent subsequence of some arbitrary sequence.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried to imagine one example, in order to understand what the statement actually means.

Comment: @bonifaz: Yes, and that’s usually a very good idea. It’s just that in this case non-trivial examples are at least as hard to work with as the proof itself!

Answer (score 1):

Follows immediately from [Bolzano-Weierstrass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Just go through the proof of this theorem until you understand it.

Comment: The OP knows that it follows from the general theorem and is trying to get a sense of why the general theorem is true by looking at examples. It just happens that in this case examples aren’t very informative.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott ,  The proof for his example follows immediately from the proof of the theorem. Just take the "peaks" of the sin function and that's the convergent subsequence.

Comment: That’s beside the point: the OP was trying to get some intuition **before** tackling the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Not just for some closed interval (say $[0,1]$), but also for any interval which is a subset of $[-|M|,|M|]$ for some $M$, your statement (in title) is true.

According to the Sequential Compactness Theorem, every sequence has a monotone subsequence, and since every subsequence of a bounded sequence is also bounded and since a monotone bounded sequence is convergent, so every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence.